# Linux Boot-Record vanishes after a few days

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot

In my pc I am using a dual boot system. I have Windows 10 and Linux Mint installed on my SSD.

Windows 10 was installed first, later I partitioned 30GB of free space to EXT4, and installed Mint by choosing "Install Linux Mint in addition to Windows".

On startup, I always get the boot-menu, where I can choose between Mint and Windows Boot Manager.

*However, after about a week or so, my pc always starts booting right into Windows.*

I already looked up in the UEFI Bios and did not find the Linux Boot Record any more. Of course, I did not make any changes to both of the systems, that could have caused this.

Also this is now the fourth time this happened. Approximately a week long, I can and have used both systems without trouble multiple times. Then suddenly my Linux Boot record is just gone, or at least not available to select in UEFI Bios.

However, using Partition Wizard Free, I can confirm, that the Ext 4 partition ist still there.

I could not find anything regarding this issue directly on the internet.

I tried a few adjecent "fixes" like disabling fast boot in Windows 10, but it did not help.

Comment: This OS selection boot menu is coming from the EFI, or from the Grub? What you did in the previous events, how did you fix it? Please extend these into your question, or answer in a comment.

Comment: The boot menu came from the GNU GRUB Version 2.something.
Also I did not really fix it before. I assumed something went wrong with the installation the first two times and just wiped the partition and did a clean fresh installation of linux. Only this time i tried to analyse this issue and found out, that the partition is still there and assumed that just the boot record got missing somehow